# Examples of a problem solved by a well-chosen derivative equaling zero

Tags: calculus, soft-question, derivatives

What are examples of problems which are solved by taking a derivative of a well-chosen function, and finding that it is zero, therefore the function must be constant?

I can think of a few:

- Show $\int_0^pf(t)dt = \int_a^{a+p}f(t)dt$ for $f$ periodic of period $p$. This can be solved by differentiating $\int_0^pf(t)dt - \int_a^{a+p}f(t)dt$ with respect to $a$, noting that it is zero, and noting that the function has value zero at $a=0$.
- Show that $\int_1^a \frac1t dt = \int_b^ab \frac1t dt$. This can be shown by differentiating $\int_1^a \frac1t dt - \int_b^ab \frac1t dt$ with respect to $b$, noting that it is zero, and noting that the function is zero ab $b=1$.
- A bounded harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ must be constant, since we can show by mean value property that $|\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}| \leq C/r \cdot \max_{\|x\| =r}|u|$ for any $r$, so sending $r$ to infinity shows $u$ is a constant.

I note that both of these first two problems are similar in that what is of interest is in the limits of an integral. I was looking for some other examples, perhaps not sharing this similarity. I'm sure there are far too many examples to list, but who has some good ones?

Answer (score 1):

In elementary calculus, one  shows that the solutions of   $\frac{dy}{dt}=ky$ are $y=Ce^{kt}$ by letting $w=ye^{-kt}$. Then $\frac{dw}{dt}=0$.

Comment: Good one!------